# Python: "The label is not in the columns" error after pd.read_csv(..., index_col='year')

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to access a column in my data frame however it's not working

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(data, index_col='year')
dfyear = df.loc[:,'year']
```

I get the following error:

```
KeyError: 'the label [year] is not in the [columns]'
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you `print(df.head(5))` to show us what data you're working with?

Comment: Side note: you can just do `df.plot(y='average_ridership', use_index=True)` to get the plot you want without assigning the series `dfyear` or `dfridership` I think (not seeing the plot or the data I can't say for sure).

Comment: Because `pd.read_csv(..., index_col='year')` is [explicitly telling it to drop 'year' as a column and use it for row-indices](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), as the doc says. If you don't want to do that, then don't do that. Just read 'year' along with the other columns. This is a near-duplicate of many existing questions.

Comment: Try df.index since I guess year is an index

Answer (score 4):

I think `year` is your index.  Try `dfyear = df.index` instead of `dfyear = df.loc[:,'year']`